# Extract results from a web page using a range in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to extract data to excel via the web.  The code below works fine, but instead of having the "URL;http://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_6-6378.php" in the body of the code I want to link to a particular cell within Excel (ie =Range("B2") )that has that reference and so that when a selection changes and refreshed the correct data is extracted.  I'm missing something...

```
Sub GetData()
    'Network Extraction
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_6-6378.php", Destination:=Range( _
        "$C$4"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "1"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I worked it out.  I used connstring = Range("A2")   and then Connection:=connstring and this works perfectly.

Comment: Can you add your own answer to this question and accept it so that others know this is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Following the guidance [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que), this answer by the OP  (@Stewart Setter) has been edited out of the question and put as an answer.

Author's text:

I have resolved this now.  See below.  I used Connstring = Range("A2")  and replaced the URL Web address with Connection:=Connstring.

```
Sub GetData()
    Connstring = Range("A2")
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Connstring, Destination:=Range( _
                                                                           "$C$24"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "4"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = False    'xx
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @StewartSetter. Answers should not be edited into the question. If you wish to answer your question, for example to earn rep,  just leave a comment on the community wiki answer, and I'll delete it.